# SSL_get_ex_new_index,SSL_CTX_get_ex_data, SSL_CTX_set_ex_data return wrong value

Tags: c++, c, ssl, encryption, openssl

I have situation where a single client initiates SSL session with two servers.
During `SSL_CTX_set_verify` callback function verification I am trying to use `SSL_CTX_set_ex_data` / `SSL_CTX_get_ex_data`.

Mine is a single threaded process with two different SSL sessions.
I am fetching index value from `SSL_get_ex_new_index` and saving application data in that index using 1st sessions `SSL*`.
Likewise it is done for 2nd session with its corresponding `SSL*`.

```
static int mydata_index=-1;//declared globally

initSSL()

{

//setting data from 1st sessions class scope followed by 2nd session

SSL_set_ex_data(m_ssl,mydata_index,remote_ip);

mydata_index = SSL_get_ex_new_index(0,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
.............................
...............................

}

//fetching app data during verify_callback

verify_callback()

{
...................

SSL *ssl;

ssl =(SSL*)X509_STORE_CTX_get_ex_data(ctx, SSL_get_ex_data_X509_STORE_CTX_idx());

char *mydata_ssl =(char*)SSL_get_ex_data(ssl,mydata_index);

}
```

While retrieving app data using `SSL_CTX_get_ex_data` using the (global index,1st session SSL*) I am getting the 2nd sessions data.

Comment: Why are you using global variables, and obsolete function definitions?

Comment: what do you mean by obsolete?These are still used right?

Comment: Only for compatibility with legacy code. These days we write `void initSSL(void)` if that's what is intended.

Comment: apart from initSSL , how do you write per session specific application data which are to be used in verify callback functions,